# What happens to the blocks that do not pass the acceptance rules?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, p2p

One of the acceptance rule for the blocks is that the block timestamp cannot be more than 2 hours in the future. What happens to blocks whose timestamp does not meet this rule, i.e. blocks that generally do not meet **the acceptance rules** (not consensus rules)? Are they rejected as if they had never been seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block with a timestamp too far in the future is invalid. This seems to be discovered during `ProcessNewBlockHeaders` when learning about the block header. The node discards the invalid block header.

```cpp
// Check timestamp
if (block.Time() > now + std::chrono::seconds{MAX_FUTURE_BLOCK_TIME}) {
    return state.Invalid(BlockValidationResult::BLOCK_TIME_FUTURE, "time-too-new", "block timestamp too far in the future");
}
```

via [src/validation.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e3b68b3b833984973401ceff43930f7c56a83f29/src/validation.cpp#L3807-L3810)